# Replace all varchar column declarations with a size greater than 8000

Tags: mysql, sql-server, regex, vb.net, parsing

I have a sql dump file from MySQL that I use to create SQL Server (2005) tables out of.

I need to change the column declarations that are greater than varchar(8000), the max for sql server 2005, to varchar(max).

I am using a Visual Basic script to parse through the dump file and make these changes. It just looks at the whole file as a string. I only want to change if the number is greater than 8000, but I don't know how to do this. Is there a way to check what that number is inside of the declaration and change it? I've made a regular expression to find the number inside the declaration. But I don't know of a way to say:

For all strings that match varchar(int>8000), change to varchar(max).

Comment: write a regex to pull all numbers between `(` and `)` and compare that to 8000. if > 8000, replace with `MAX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex to match a number greater than (or equal to) 8000: `/^([89]\d{3}|\d{5,})$/`

Where `/` is a delimiter for the regex, followed by start (`^`) followed by either (`(...|...)`) an 8 or 9 and 3 more digits (`[89]\d{3}`) or five or more digits (`\d{5,}`) followed by the end of the string (`$`) and regex delimiter (`/`).

To use in your context, something like this should do it...

```
/varchar\(\s*([89]\d{3}|\d{5,})\s*\)/
```

This has escaped braces `\(...\)` and optional spaces `\s*` and your keyword `varchar`

Comment: Trying this: `s.Replace("/varchar\(\s*([89]\d{3}|\d{5,})\s*\)/", "varchar(max)")` But it's not changing anything.

Comment: is it perhaps only changing the first one? maybe you need a global flag - but I don't know where to add that in `vb.net`. Also, you might not need the delimiters, so just try getting rid of the `/` at the start and end. These are language specific nuances of regex that I am not familiar with in `vb.net`